# Merge rows with common two common values | Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling on what it seems a simple merge between rows. I have two pandas DataFrames with the following column values

```
df_a.columns.to_list()
['id','food','color','type','shape']

df_b.columns.to_list()
['id','food','smell','date']
```

I want to see if there are foods repeated in both DataFrames to merge them in just one

```
df_total = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], keys=['A', 'B'], ignore_index=False)
df_total = df_total.sort_values(by=['food'],ascending=True);
df_total['food'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>=2]

Out[1]
apple       2
cheese      2
```

According to this, "APPLE" and "CHEESE" are duplicated. When printing the concatenated table we get

```
id     food     color     type     shape     smell       date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1     apple     red      fruit    round      NaN         NaT
 1     apple     NaN       NaN      NaN      soft     2020-06-05
 2     cheese  yellow     dairy   squared     NaN         NaT
 2     cheese    NaN       NaN      NaN      soft     2020-06-07
 3     lemon    green     fruit    round      NaN         NaT
```

Desired output:

```
id     food     color     type     shape     smell       date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1     apple     red      fruit    round     soft     2020-06-05
 2     cheese  yellow     dairy   squared    soft     2020-06-07
 3     lemon    green     fruit    round      NaN         NaT
```

**My attempt:**

Redefine **df_total** this time with **pd.merge** using **.reset_index** in both DataFrames.

```
df_total = pd.merge(df_a.reset_index(),df_b.reset_index(), how = 'right/left/outer/inner')
```

For *how* I have used the values of "right", "left", "outer", "inner" but it merges them in such way as if I just had deleted one of the rows or with no values at all. How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Please add more data as it seems impossible to generate your desired output with what you provide.

Comment: @CeliusStingher There is much more data to it, there are about 60 rows. Just displayed some rows to make it simple. All the rows that are duplicated follow the same pattern, one row has "color", "type" and "shape" but missing "smell" and "date" and the other row viceversa.

Comment: Understood, maybe my answer helps you solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take advantage of the first/last capabilities of groupby.

In this case:

```
df.groupby(['food']).last().reset_index()
```

Output

```
        1  0       2      3        4     5           6
0   apple  1     red  fruit    round  soft  2020-06-05
1  cheese  2  yellow  dairy  squared  soft  2020-06-07
2   lemon  3   green  fruit    round   NaN         NaT
```

Comment: Nice combination of groupby + last :) +1

Comment: Does this work too if the rows with repeated values are not together?

Comment: They become together once they are grouped.  However you may want to apply a sort first to ensure they are in the order you like.

Answer (score 4):

Given the output you generate, because the data you provide is incomplete, I would solve the issue by using `.drop_duplicates()`, by taking advantage of its parameters `subset` and `keep` while previously using `bfill()` to take care of the missing values:

```
desired_output = original_output.bfill().drop_duplicates('food',keep='first')
```

As an example, starting from your undesired output:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame({'food':['apple','apple','cheese','cheese','lemon'],
                           'color':['red',np.nan,'yellow',np.nan,'green'],
                           'type':['fruit',np.nan,'dairy',np.nan,'fruit'],
                           'shape':['round',np.nan,'squared',np.nan,'round'],
                           'smell':[np.nan,'soft',np.nan,'soft',np.nan],
                           'date':[np.nan,'2020-06-05',np.nan,'2020-06-07',np.nan]})
```

With the following line:

```
desired_df = original_df.bfill().drop_duplicates('food',keep='first')
```

Outputs:

```
     food   color   type    shape smell        date
0   apple     red  fruit    round  soft  2020-06-05
2  cheese  yellow  dairy  squared  soft  2020-06-07
4   lemon   green  fruit    round   NaN         NaN
```

Comment: If my understanding is correc, **.drop_duplicates(keep='first')** is using the first row of the repeated values and attaching to it the values of the other repeated rows, right? Also, does this make useless the alphabetical ordering?

Comment: `drop_duplicates(keep='first')` simply drops the rows where the `food` column is duplicated, keeping the first one only. By using `bfill()` previously, we're replacing the `NaN` values with the further ones, for each `food` the alphabetical is necessary. Otherwise, we would need to first `groupby`, and use `bfill()` which is a valid and consistent alternative.